# Regex to select first two characters from string and remove rest of the string

Tags: regex, string

I want to select first two characters appearing on a given string like below.
 in below example i would like the result to show "CJ" only.

";2;14;1;1;***CJ***;1;CT;1;DG;1;DJ;1;DT;1;QF;1;QG;1;QH;1;TA;1;TG;1;TK;1;TR;1;TW;1;TX";

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
([a-zA-Z]{2})
```

> (): Capture the string into a group
>
> [a-zA-Z]: Match any letter, upper or lower case
>
> {2}: Match exactly 2 times

Make sure the "global" flag is not enabled ("global" allows returning multiple matches, not just the first)

Comment: Great Kyle, I see it matches to all Characters in string now,however i just need to match with first two characters. So "CJ" only want to ignore rest ( CT,GD,DJ etc..)

Comment: Right - this is why you want to ensure the "global" flag is DISABLED.  Which language are you using?  Also, check out regex101.com to help with complex regex strings...